# Routing all local traffic not through the VPN

Tags: networking, routing

I connect to VPN in pptp configuration in windows os.

By default - the all local traffic is routed through the VPN.

I wont to route all local traffic (https://ipinfo.io/bogon) through the original interface and not via the VPN.

What's the easiest way to do this?
I need to do this on many computers, so I am looking for an easy way, like a script, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should happen by default on a typical home/small network where the LAN comprises 1 subnet. This is because Internet traffic uses the most specific route, and your LAN is more specific then the "everything" (default gateway) route.

To extend this to a more complex network which make use of other RFC1918/bogon ranges you can add each of those ranges to the routing table (typically with a default gateway of your router). Because they are again more specific then the default route over the VPN they will be preferred.

Comment: I'm looking for a script that automatically makes these routes

Comment: You did not specify the VPN software or OS so no one can provide specific advice without more info. PPTP is an (insecure) protocol - not software.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the question body.